# Make dropdown child 100% of container

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown inside a black container of 600px and i would like to have the red childrens show in a width of 100% of container instead of 100% of page width as it happens now. I need this to be in % because the website is responsive.

Please take a look at [Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pnwd72d1/8/)

```
<div id="navcontainer">
    <ul>

        <li style="display: inline;float: left;">
            <a href="#">Filters</a>

            <ul style="text-align:left">
                <li><a href="">Brand</a></li>

                <li><a href="">Model</a></li>

                <li><a href="">Color</a></li>

                <li><a href="">Features</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li style="display: inline;float: right;">
            <a href="#">Sort by</a>

            <ul style="text-align:right">
                <li><a href="">Newest</a></li>

                <li><a href="">Oldest</a></li>

                <li><a href="">Cheapest</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add `position:relative;` for - `#navcontainer ul`

```css
#navcontainer {
    background:#222;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
}
#navcontainer ul {
    text-align:center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#navcontainer ul li {
    display:inline;
    /*position:relative;*/
}
#navcontainer ul li a {
    display:inline-block;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:20px 30px;
}
#navcontainer ul li a:hover {
    background:#999;
}
#navcontainer ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:100%;
    z-index:10;
    width:100%;
    display:none;
    background:red;
}
#navcontainer ul ul li {
    float:none;
}
#navcontainer ul ul li a {
    text-align:left;
}
#navcontainer ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="navcontainer">
        <ul>
 
            <li>
                <a href="#">Eggs</a>
 
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">sub menu</a></li>
 
                    <li><a href="">sub menu</a></li>
 
                    <li><a href="">sub menu</a></li>
 
                    <li><a href="">sub menu</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but i forgot something. I have updated the jsfiddle. I need it to float to right side and have this code #navcontainer ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}

Answer (score 0):

you can use position attribute for many diffrent uses but there you need to hava a contained sub menu and you cant use position:absolute; for parent element 
you can use it for child elements and here you do it for both of theme .
change this line to solve your problem .

```
#navcontainer ul ul {
    position:relative;
}
```

sorry for my bad language skils .

Comment: Thanks but i forgot something. I have updated the jsfiddle. I need it to float to right side and have this code #navcontainer ul li { display: inline; float: right; }

Comment: it won't change anything but if it is possible update jsfiddle for show problem

Comment: I have updated the original jsfiddle - red submenu is bigger than the black menu - it must be 100% to keep it responsive

Comment: i cab't find out what's your problem with first type

Comment: As you can see in the updated jsfiddle, the black bar have a width of 600px and when i hover over "Eggs", the red submenu is wider than the black parent.

Comment: Ok , I see , answer is in next post

Answer (score 0):

The above description and view the demo you away into a problem solved
You should add the parent element the following characteristics :

```
#navcontainer {
    background: rgb(34, 34, 34) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 65px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 600px;
}
```